# Trying to swap the maximum and the minimum numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, max, min

I'm trying to swap the maximum and minimum values in an array in my program.
Here is the code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int myArray[] = new int[25];

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        myArray[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    int maximum = maxNumber(myArray);
    int minimum = minNumber(myArray);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
}
```

```java
public static int maxNumber(int[] arr) {
    int maximumValue = arr[0];
    //finds the maximum value in an array
    for (int a = 1; a < arr.length; a++) {
        if (arr[a] > maximumValue) {
            maximumValue = arr[a];
        }
    }
    return maximumValue;
}
```

```java
public static int minNumber(int[] arr) {
    int minimumValue = arr[0];
    //finds the minimum value in an array
    for (int a = 1; a < arr.length; a++) {
        if (arr[a] < minimumValue) {
            minimumValue = arr[a];
        }
    }
    return minimumValue;
}
```

I have two separate functions to find the Maximum and Minimum values, but I'm stuck on the actual swapping of the values. The two functions work as I've used them for another program, but I'm not sure if they would work for this program.

At first I was thinking of finding them by setting them equal to each other in some way, but that led to nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should not get the max *value* but the *index* of the max value, same thing for min. And then you switch the values at those indices.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arr = new int[25];

    System.out.format("Enter array int numbers (%d in total): ", arr.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        arr[i] = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    swamMinMax(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}

private static void swamMinMax(int[] arr) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        min = Math.min(min, arr[i]);
        max = Math.max(max, arr[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == min)
            arr[i] = max;
        else if (arr[i] == max)
            arr[i] = min;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter array int numbers (25 in total): 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 -1 -1 -1 14 15 16  17 18 19 20 21 22 23 66 66
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 66, 66]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 66, 66, 66, 1, 1, 1, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, -1, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You were real close.  I copied some of the code and commented where the changes need to be made.  You can still use your existing code to populate the array from the console.

Also, kudos for assigning the first element in the array to min or max and starting your loop at 1.  A lot of folks don't think about doing that.

```
int myArray[] = {1,10,-5,99,48,-22,43, 44,100,2};
    
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));   // print original array
int maxIdx = maxNumber(myArray);                // get index of max
int minIdx = minNumber(myArray);                // get index of min
    
// now swap max and min using the returned indices.
int save = myArray[maxIdx];
myArray[maxIdx] = myArray[minIdx];
myArray[minIdx] = save;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));   // print the altered array

    
public static int maxNumber(int[] arr) {
    int maximumValue = arr[0];
    // finds the maximum value in an array
    int idx = 0;                                    //idx = 0 to start
    for (int a = 1; a < arr.length; a++) {
        if (arr[a] > maximumValue) {
            idx = a;                                //save index of current max
            maximumValue = arr[a];
        }
    }
    return idx;                                     // return index of max
}
    
public static int minNumber(int[] arr) {
    int minimumValue = arr[0];
    // finds the minimum value in an array
    int idx = 0;                                    // idx = 0 to start
    for (int a = 1; a < arr.length; a++) {
        if (arr[a] < minimumValue) {
            idx = a;                                // save index of current min
            minimumValue = arr[a];
        }
    }
    return idx;                                     // return index of min
}
```

This would print

```
[1, 10, -5, 99, 48, -22, 43, 44, 100, 2]
[1, 10, -5, 99, 48, 100, 43, 44, -22, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) to find indexes of the maximum and minimum elements and then swap their values:

```java
int[] arr = {1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2, 8, 7, 9, -1, -3};
```

```java
// indexes of the maximum and minimum elements
int max = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        .boxed().max(Comparator.comparing(i -> arr[i])).orElse(-1);

int min = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        .boxed().min(Comparator.comparing(i -> arr[i])).orElse(-1);
```

```java
// swap the values
int temp = arr[max];
arr[max] = arr[min];
arr[min] = temp;
```

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// [1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2, 8, 7, -3, -1, 9]
```